# how drag and drop from tree list to windows file system?

Tags: c++, file, drag-and-drop

I need drag and drop item, which represent file, to windows file system in C++. For how i can only drag and drop file from filesystem to my program, but how do that in opposite way?

Answer (score 2):

You have to send a `WM_DROPFILES` message to the target window somehow. In the process, you have to make it global memory, so that you can send a pointer to the `DROPFILES` structure, because otherwise you can't send pointers to other processes, since the memory isn't actually allocated on the other end.

Assigning the `DROPFILES` structure is ridiculous, because apparently all files in the list are supposed to be stored in a single `DWORD` value from what I've seen, which can't be the case, and hasn't been working for me at all.

This post will at least give you an understanding of which direction to go in your searches for information, good luck.